# Disable automatic sleep with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, disable

The tabs on Google Chrome get inactive in 4 minutes of no using, and this stop my activity in an online game like diep.io and get disconnected, I want to disable this option, is that possible?

I have installed some extensions in Google Chrome, The great suspender and Disable automatic tab discarding, but didn`t work, is there any possible way to do it?